# psql swiss tournament system - prevent rematches between 2 player

Tags: database-design, database-schema, psql, unique-constraint

```
CREATE TABLE matches (
  match_id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  tournamentid INTEGER,
  winner_id INTEGER,
  loser_id INTEGER CHECK (winner_id != loser_id),
  draw BOOLEAN,
  FOREIGN KEY(tournamentid, winner_id) REFERENCES enroll(tournament,   player_id),
  FOREIGN KEY(tournamentid, loser_id) REFERENCES enroll(tournament, player_id),
  UNIQUE(tournamentid, winner_id, loser_id)
);
```

This is the current match table schema. i m trying to figure out a way to prevent player 1 from playing against player 2 twice. so for example i have the followings:

INSERT INTO matches(tournamentid, winner_id, loser_id, draw) VALUES('1', '2', '3', 'false');

INSERT INTO matches(tournamentid, winner_id, loser_id, draw) VALUES('1', '3', '2', 'false');

these two queries are essentially the same and both will be allowed. my question is if there's a way to disallow the second query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with that schema.  Some DBMSs allow subqueries in check constraints, which could've been used here.

Instead, you can try:

```
CREATE TABLE matches (
  match_id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  tournamentid INTEGER,
  player1_id INTEGER,
  player2_id INTEGER CHECK (player1_id < player2_id),
  result SMALLINT CHECK (result IN (0, 1, 2)),
  FOREIGN KEY(tournamentid, player1_id) REFERENCES enroll(tournament, player_id),
  FOREIGN KEY(tournamentid, player2_id) REFERENCES enroll(tournament, player_id),
  UNIQUE(tournamentid, player1_id, player2_id)
);
```

where 0 indicates a draw, 1 or 2 a win for the corresponding player.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried adding a lower_id column but i realized it also prevented a player with the smaller number from playing against any players with bigger numbers. bummer. the other alternative that you suggested doesn't really change anything except the way winners and losers are represented. correct me if I'm wrong but there's gotta be a way to say (player1, player2) is the same as (player2, player1).

Comment: You're right, the lower_id suggestion won't work.  However, the second suggestion enables and forces players to be inserted as an ordered pair, which together with the unique constraint (tournamentid, player1_id, player2_id) should prevent duplicates.